# Full Calendar showing All Day Events

Tags: php, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar, the calendar is utilizing Google Calendar API to bring in the events.

I am having an issue with the events displaying as All Day for their time slots when viewed in the `agendaWeek` and `agendaDay`. This prevents the user from displaying their events properly and they're having a difficult time identifying where their availability is within the day, or week.

I have confirmed that the events have times from 8am to 10am for example.

Any on ideas? Having a difficult time sorting this one out.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    buttonIcons: {
        prev: 'circle-triangle-w',
        next: 'circle-triangle-e'
    },
    <?php if($jsonEvents !='') { ?>
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
      allday:false;
      var selectDate = "";
      var selectTime = "";
      if(view.name !="month") {
        if(allDay) {
          selectDate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate( date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        }
        else {
          selectDate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate( date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
          selectTime = $.fullCalendar.formatDate( date, 'hh:mm TT');
        }
      }
      else {
        selectDate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate( date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
      }

      if( selectDate !="") {
        $("#startDate").val(selectDate);
        $('#startDate').datepicker('setValue', selectDate);
        $("#endDate").val(selectDate);
        $('#endDate').datepicker('setValue', selectDate);
      }

      if(selectTime !="")   {
        $("#startTime").val(selectTime);
        $('#startTime').timepicker({'timeFormat': 'h:i A', 'scrollDefaultNow': true , 'forceRoundTime': true }).on('change', function(ev){
          $('#endTime').val(Add30Min($(this).val()));
          $('#endTime').timepicker({'timeFormat': 'h:i A', 'scrollDefaultNow': true , 'forceRoundTime': true, 'minTime': selectTime});
        });
        $("#endTime").val(Add30Min(selectTime));
        $('#endTime').timepicker({'timeFormat': 'h:i A', 'scrollDefaultNow': true , 'forceRoundTime': true, 'minTime': selectTime});
      }
      $("#eventId").val("");
      $("#mainModalHead").text("Add Event");
      $("#hidEditEventId").val("");
      $("#EventModal").modal();
    },


    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

      var startDayName = $.fullCalendar.formatDate( calEvent.start, 'ddd');
      var startMonthName = $.fullCalendar.formatDate( calEvent.start, 'MMM dd');
      var startTime = $.fullCalendar.formatDate( calEvent.start, 'hh:mm TT');
      var startDetails = startDayName+", "+startMonthName+", "+startTime;

      var endDayName = $.fullCalendar.formatDate( calEvent.end, 'ddd');
      var endMonthName = $.fullCalendar.formatDate( calEvent.end, 'MMM dd');
      var endTime = $.fullCalendar.formatDate( calEvent.end, 'hh:mm TT');
      var endDetails = endDayName+", "+endMonthName+", "+endTime;

      var eventDetails = startDetails+" - "+endDetails;
      $("#googleEventTitle").text(calEvent.title);
      $("#googleEventBody").text(eventDetails);
      $("#eventId").val(calEvent.id);
      $("#hidEventName").val(calEvent.title);
      $("#hidStartDate").val($.fullCalendar.formatDate( calEvent.start, 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
      $("#hidStartTime").val($.fullCalendar.formatDate( calEvent.start, 'hh:mm TT'));
      $("#hidEndDate").val($.fullCalendar.formatDate( calEvent.end, 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
      $("#hidEndTime").val($.fullCalendar.formatDate( calEvent.end, 'hh:mm TT'));
      $("#eventDelete").attr("disabled", false);
      $("#eventEdit").attr("disabled", false);
      $("#EditDeleteOperationModal").modal();
    },

    <?php } ?>
    weekNumbers : false,
    weekMode : 'fixed',
    editable: false,
    <?php if($jsonEvents !='') { ?>
      events: <?php echo $jsonEvents; ?>,
    <?php } ?>
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
    eventColor: '#3c8dbc',
    eventTextColor: '#ffffff'
});
```

Here is the json Event List.

```
$eventItems = $eventList['items']; //From Google        
$x=0;
$events   = array();
$startDateTime ='';
$endDateTime ='';
$summary = '';
$start = array();
$end = array();

foreach($eventItems as $item) {
    if(isset($item['summary'])) {

         $summary = $item['summary'];

    }
    $start = $item['start'];
    if(isset($start['dateTime'])) { 

        $startDateTime = $start['dateTime'];

    }
    else if(isset($start['date'])) {

        $startDateTime = $start['date'];

    }
    $end = $item['end'];
    if(isset($end['dateTime'])) {

        $endDateTime = $end['dateTime'];

    }
    else if(isset($end['date'])) {

        $endDateTime = $end['date'];

    }

    $events[$x]['id']               = $item['id'];          
    $events[$x]['title']            = $summary;
    $events[$x]['start']            = $startDateTime;
    $events[$x]['end']              = $endDateTime;
    $events[$x]['allDay']           = true;
    $events[$x]['backgroundColor']  = '#0092D0';
    $x++;
}
$jsonEvents = json_encode($events);
```

}

`$jsonEvents` returns the following;

```
string(3742) "[{
    "id":"32rsm3h04dsuoikk2r1arfc3m0_20170624T160000Z","title":"Car payment $330.00 28th","start":"2017-06-24T09:00:00-07:00","end":"2017-06-24T10:00:00-07:00","allDay":true,"backgroundColor":"#0092D0"},
}]"
```

`jsonEvents` is built like

```
$eventList  = $cal->events->listEvents(
    'primary',
    array(
        'timeMin' =>''.$pastEvents.'T01:00:00Z',
        'timeMax' =>''.$futureEvents.'T23:59:59Z',
        'singleEvents' => true
    )
);
$eventItems = $eventList['items']; //From Google        
$x=0;
$events   = array();
$startDateTime ='';
$endDateTime ='';
$summary = '';
$start = array();
$end = array();

foreach($eventItems as $item) {
    if(isset($item['summary'])) {

         $summary = $item['summary'];

    }
    $start = $item['start'];
    if(isset($start['dateTime'])) { 

        $startDateTime = $start['dateTime'];

    }
    else if(isset($start['date'])) {

        $startDateTime = $start['date'];

    }
    $end = $item['end'];
    if(isset($end['dateTime'])) {

        $endDateTime = $end['dateTime'];

    }
    else if(isset($end['date'])) {

        $endDateTime = $end['date'];

    }

    $events[$x]['id']               = $item['id'];          
    $events[$x]['title']            = $summary;
    $events[$x]['start']            = $startDateTime;
    $events[$x]['end']              = $endDateTime;
    $events[$x]['allDay']           = true;
    $events[$x]['backgroundColor']  = '#0092D0';
    $x++;
}
$jsonEvents = json_encode($events);
```

}

Comment: You should post the content of `$jsonEvents`... I guess there is no `start` and `end` property. See [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/).

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I added the jsonEvents.

Comment: That is how you reformat the data... And it looks correct. But I meant to check the json content itself. Try `console.log("<?php echo $jsonEvents; ?>");` to check if there is a start and end time. Maybe it's there but not properly formatted. It has to be ISO 8601.

Comment: you need to show us the actual JSON data so we can see if it's correct. The most likely reason is that the start/end dates are empty or invalid. BTW did you know fullCalendar can interact directly with Google Calendar as a built in feature? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/

Comment: I have updated my OP with the information requested @ADyson

Comment: See OP for information @LouysPatriceBessette

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the issue about `allDay`.

There is a conflict between your use of `start` / `end` and `allDay`.

From the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/):

> If all else fails, FullCalendar will try to guess. If either the start or end value has a "T" as part of the ISO8601 date string, allDay will become false. Otherwise, it will be true.

Seems like "forcing" it to `true` when FullCalendar tries to overide it to `false` is causing that issue.

***Maybe*** that could be reported as a bug... Since there is no error thrown.
**Having at least an error would help.**
I suggest you submit a bug report and see their answer about it. ;)

---

**But for now**, your json generation looks perfect. Your issue is the data.
When you use ISO 8601 strings as `start` / `end`, do not set all day to `true`.

**OR** set it to `true`, but only provide a `start` date... And date only, no time.
Having `allDay` to true make the `end` superflous... don't provide it.

Here is a [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/yzBvEq?editors=0011) I used to nail this out.

Comment: mmm... From the CodePen??

Comment: I set allday to false, and now it works from the json data.

Comment: And you understand why? I mean... You undestand in which condition it has to be false?

Comment: I do understand why. What I need to find out now is how to idenfiy if a event is set to an allday event through google so that I can toggle that one specific event, and leave others set to false if they have a start/end date.

Comment: run a if/else statement; If start & end is null, then set to true, else set to false.

Comment: You coud split the `start` and `end` to the `T` and keep index 1 (the time). Then check it if is really supposed to be "allDay". In the provided json, you had start = 09:00:00 and end= 10:00:00 --- Can't be all day.

Comment: I guess start = 00:00:00 and end = 23:59:59 is "all day"... (Didn't test it.. Need to test it from Google's data, which is a new information about this question, by the way...).

Comment: Awesome, thats really helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

i test with this format allDay worked but how i change a event to allDay dynamically,

```
    {
      title: "simple event",
      start: "2021-06-14 14:00:00",
      end: "2021-06-14 15:00:00",
      allDay : true
    },
```